# How do you read a value at a specific index of a TabularData Dataframe?

Tags: swift, csv, indexing, tabular

I am a beginner in Swift, and I just learned I could import csv with tabular data. However, even though I now have a slice (I am not sure what the specific type is), I can't figure out how to access an index in there. I want to read row 0 and column 4 (location).

Picture of the Dataframe slice:

[image: Picture of the Dataframe slice]

```swift
var convert = try DataFrame(contentsOfCSVFile: URL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shadowdragon2805/CrimeData/main/docs/csv/zip_code_database.csv")!, columns: columns, types: ["zip": .string, "primary_city": .string, "state": .string, "county": .string, "latitude": .double, "longitude": .double])
let new = convert.filter(on: "zip", String.self){$0 == "00501"}
```

`new` is the name of my slice that I just filtered. I want to access an index of this table but I can't.
I have tried many ways but all have given me an error:

---

```swift
let index = new.subscript(r: 0, c: 4)
```

but that results in the error:

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'AnyColumnSlice'

```swift
let index = new.index(0, 4)
```

also results in:

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'AnyColumnSlice'

```swift
let index = new(row: 0, column: 4)
```

but that results in:

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'DataFrame.Slice'

```swift
let index = new[0][4]
```

but that results in:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'String'

How can I access index [0][4] so I can find the location on this table?

Comment: `new.column[0][4]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways of accessing a specific value in a data frame slice. The closest to your attempts is probably:

```
let latitude = new.rows[0][4, Double.self]
```

Note that `new[row: 0][4, Double.self]` would have worked if `new` were a [`DataFrame`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tabulardata/dataframe), but unfortunately `new` is a [`DataFrame.Slice`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tabulardata/dataframe/slice) here which doesn't have the [`subscript(row:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tabulardata/dataframe/subscript(row:)) subscript for some reason.

You can also access the column by name, which I recommend:

```
let latitude = new.row[0]["latitude", Double.self]
```

You can also access the column first:

```
let latitude = new["latitude", Double.self][0]
// or
let latitude = new[column: 4, Double.self][0]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! My code now compiles! :)) Also just a clarification, readLine() does not work in playground right?(I'm in playground right now and it skips over readLine())

Comment: @LindaXue did I mention `readLine` anywhere?

Comment: Yeah sorry, it was a general question but don't worry I figured that out. Thanks!